# Django + React Axios instance header conflict?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, axios

I have all my functions based views on django protected with `@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])` so I have to send a JWT as Bearer token on every request.
In the first version I was using this code:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { decodeUserJWT } from '../../extras'
const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
var decoded = decodeUserJWT(user.access);
var user_id = decoded.user_id

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/api',
    headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + user.access},
    params: {userAuth: user_id}
});

export default instance;
```

Everything was working fine.

But then I added interceptors so I could handle the refreshToken process:

```
const setup = (store) => {
  axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
    (config) => {
      const token = TokenService.getLocalAccessToken();
      if (token) {
        // const uid = await decodeUserJWT(token);
        config.headers["Authorization"] = 'Bearer ' + token;
        // config.headers["userAuth"] = uid;
      }
      return config;
    },
    (error) => {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  );
  const { dispatch } = store;
  axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
    (res) => {
      return res;
    },
    async (err) => {
      const originalConfig = err.config;
      if (originalConfig.url !== "/auth/token/obtain/" && err.response) {
        console.log("TOKEN INTERCEPTOR");
        // Access Token was expired
        if (err.response.status === 401 && !originalConfig._retry) {
          originalConfig._retry = true;
          try {
            const rs = await axiosInstance.post("/auth/token/refresh/", {
              refresh: TokenService.getLocalRefreshToken(),
            });
            const { access } = rs.data;
            dispatch(refreshToken(access));
            TokenService.updateLocalAccessToken(access);
            return axiosInstance(originalConfig);
          } catch (_error) {
            return Promise.reject(_error);
          }
        }
      }
      return Promise.reject(err);
    }
  );
};
```

What happens?
When I add the line `config.headers["userAuth"] = uid;` the django server console starts showing up that when the react app tries to access the routes it gets a `Not Authorized`, and when I take that line off de code ... it works fine.

I also tried to pass the param `userAuth` in the `axios.create` and keep only the `Bearer` config inside the interpector code, but still no positive result, the code with the interpector code only works when I take off the `userAuth` line from axios.

Any ideia on why this is happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: You don't need to use an interceptor to always send the auth header. The intended way is by setting default values on an axios instance: https://github.com/axios/axios#custom-instance-defaults Not sure what the point of the `userAuth` header is? The `Authorization` header with the bearer token should be enough. The JWT contains a claim about who your user is supposed to be. It's also not clear to me why this is related to react+redux. Are you using a custom auth middleware with redux? If so, you should provide the code or state which library this is.

Comment: @timotgl You're right, thank you for clarifying my thoughts about this